# How to use android.view.SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm trying to use the SurfaceView widget. I have a class

```
public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    public OurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.d("OurView", "Yay We started");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

So I have a SurfaceView widget in my Activity's XML. I then try to bind it in the `onCreate` method

```
TheView = (OurView) findViewById(R.id.theSurfaceView);
```

The problem is here I get an error that I can't cast `OurView` to `android.view.SurfaceView`.

I know usually I could just do this to the view itself, in the `onCreateMethod`

```
TheView = new OurView(this);
setContentView(TheView);
```

The thing is I don't want to do this, I don't want to draw on my whole activity I just want to draw on the SurfaceView widget that i've put on the layout. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your customized SurfaceView `com.xx.OurView` in your layout, not `SurfaceView`.

Comment: Oh ok I think I get it. Its so odd though my class is just a surfaceView anyway

Comment: It's not odd, it's because of the way the layout is inflated. In XML there is no such thing as inheritance, so how could the XML parser know what class you _really_ want?